# How to add files created in a custom msbuild task for build actions later?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am generating minified javascript files using a custom msbuild task. This action is done "BeforeBuild". I wish to include these generated javascript files as an "EmbeddedResource" after they are generated.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using

```
<CreateItem Include="FilesToConvert">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="EmbeddedResource" />
</CreateItem>
```